# how to display the message box showing the tasks for the day when the person logs in in c#asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having a website in which i want to display the mails that are targeted for the day once the person logs in.so how to merge the message box display code to the login information.Anyone help with code in c#

Comment: This question is difficult to understand.  You may want to provide more information and perhaps some code on what you have already tried.

Comment: Lyk i want to know how to make a popup for a person who logs in to give him the details of what are the works pending for him to be completed on that day..as a message box.

Comment: Asp is server side. So I don't believe it can react alone with the client. However, you could always use javascript. To make a messagebox call.

Comment: kindly add to the question relevant code,what you have tried so far & explain more clearly.That way people would be able to help you better

Comment: my code has a button and it will lead to getting username nad password.and it will redirect to admin page.actualy what i want is once logged in it must display the dates the mail has to be sent frm the current date to the date fixed for sending mail..using the message box code..how to do that

Answer (score 1):

This is a web page right?  You can do an alert within javascript if you like but it's really ugly and unfriendly.

So you would need to pass back to the view, all the items that need to be shown and alert them with javascript.

Or you could show a div with all the items in it that you can close.

Or you could implement jquery and have a popup modal div with all the items.

In any case, you would need, from c#, to create the html as a string and pass it back to the view using something like viewstate i think from memory.

Or maybe you can post the html into a hidden field and using javascript alert out the contents of the hidden field.

make sure you have viewstate on for the page or it won't work.

```
<input type=hidden id=hiddenField/>
```

then in c#

```
hiddenField.text = myHTML;
```

then in javascript once the page has loaded.

```
alert(document.findElementById("hiddenField").text);
```

the above code is untested but the process is what you are looking for.